# In-App Purchase vs. support developer with bitcoin

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, bitcoin

Instead of Apple offered In-App purchase I have imagined a new system to earn and save money. To sell premium service in my app, client should pay a certain amount of bitcoin i.e. with his bitcoin wallet app like [Copay](https://copay.io). In my app that would be a view called `Contribution`, where user could see all his transfer sent to my personal bitcoin account. View would have a funny title: `"There is no free beer. Support developer with X bitcoin. (appr. 1$)"` In bitcoin all the historical transfer are available for download, that what app would use to check wether he payed or not. At the bottom I will put a link, a button to a wikipedia site and youtube site, how can user use bitcoin wallet.

[App Store Review Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies) 11.13 says: Apps that link to external mechanisms for purchases or subscriptions to be used in the App, such as a "buy" button that goes to a web site to purchase a digital book, will be rejected

In my app user could get 50 piece of service for free, and from 50 each 50 would cost certain amount of bitcoin. When user reach the next 50 limit, app will automatically navigate to the `Contribution` view in the app. And user will not able to continue, until I get my bitcoin. He is not linked to a payment system in the sense he has to close my app, **manually** download / open i.e. Copay and send me the money. No Buy button will appear. But it will be obligatory to pay.

Do you think Apple will accept my so called 'support the developer' business model?

Comment: I don't think they will, but you can try and let us know

Answer (score 2):

I would be very surprised if Apple knowingly allowed you to collect money (bitcoin) for in-app functionality this way. The section of Apple's review guidelines that seems relevant to me is this one:

> 11.2 Apps utilizing a system other than the In-App Purchase API (IAP) to purchase content, functionality, or services in an App will be rejected.

To me, this means that if you want to sell functionality in your app (which is what you're planning on doing, for Bitcoin), that you will need to use Apple's In-App Purchase API instead, so that Apple gets their cut.

Here's another relevant SO discussion about 3rd-party payments in App Store apps:
[iOS app: Does Apple allow 3rd party payments inside app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12566671/ios-app-does-apple-allow-3rd-party-payments-inside-app)

Answer (score 2):

Not only do I think this will get rejected, it seems like a bad idea if you want to make money.

Unless your app targets a group of people that all regular use bitcoins or absolutely needs this app, hardly any one will do this.

You will have to put in much more effort to get this going, and you will be losing like 99% of the sales.

And I must say, Apple's share might not be cheap but is well worth it.